# why is the mips binary (built by android ndk) so much larger than those built for other targets?

Tags: android, android-ndk, mips

I have an ndk project, which uses openssl, zlib and stl libraries. When I check the dynamic library binaries, I find that the mips version is much larger than others. In my case the sizes are as below:

- mips           `1.0m`
- x86            `823k`
- armeabi    `502k`
- armeabi-v7a  `478k`

They are built from the same source code, why are the sizes so different?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I believe that mips has a smaller instruction set

Comment: make sense, smaller instruction set costs more instructions to implement same features, is it? but arm is also a risc model like mips, why its binary is even smaller than cisc x86?